# GTK: adding "desktop" flag to window

Tags: qt4, gtk, pygtk, pyqt4, desktop

I'm trying to make a window function as the desktop (the thing that displays the icons) using PyGTK. With Qt4, I can set this property to do so:

```
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_X11NetWmWindowTypeDesktop)
```

Is there anything similar for GTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found it:

```
window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DESKTOP)
```

And a very useful source: http://bloc.eurion.net/archives/2009/standalone-pygtk-desktop-widgets/